# change location of cube changes values in dict

Tags: python, blender

i tried this first, but it only put a few cubes in the right spot and did not get the right name or location for most of them

```
for bone in armature.edit_bones.values():
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=0.3, location=bone.head)
    bpy.context.active_object.name = bone.name
```

the names and locations are unpredictable.
putting the values in a dict first worked for the names but not the locations. adding a cube with bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=0.3, location=head) seems to change something when accessing values in the dict

```
# Loop through the bones in the armature
for bone in armature.edit_bones.values():
    bone_dict[bone.name] = bone.head
for name, head in bone_dict.items():
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=0.3)
    bpy.context.active_object.name = name
    #bpy.context.active_object.location = head
```

full script you can paste you can run with blender and will make a human shape armature with a bunch of named boxes (the last comment line is the part im working on that puts them on each armature)

```
import bpy
from bpy_extras import object_utils

# Select the collection to add the armature to
collection = bpy.data.collections["Collection"]
bpy.context.view_layer.active_layer_collection = bpy.context.view_layer.layer_collection.children["Collection"]

# Add a new armature to the collection and enter edit mode
armature = bpy.data.armatures.new("Armature")
obj = bpy.data.objects.new("Armature", armature)
collection.objects.link(obj)

# Select the armature
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action="DESELECT")
obj.select_set(True)

# Enter edit mode
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="EDIT")


# Create the bones for the armature
head_bone = armature.edit_bones.new('head')
neck_bone = armature.edit_bones.new('neck')
#spine_bone = armature.edit_bones.new('spine')
pelvis_bone = armature.edit_bones.new('pelvis')

# Add bones for the arms
l_shoulder_bone = armature.edit_bones.new('l_shoulder')
l_arm_bone = armature.edit_bones.new('l_arm')
r_shoulder_bone = armature.edit_bones.new('r_shoulder')
r_arm_bone = armature.edit_bones.new('r_arm')

# Add bones for the legs
l_thigh_bone = armature.edit_bones.new('l_thigh')
l_leg_bone = armature.edit_bones.new('l_leg')
r_thigh_bone = armature.edit_bones.new('r_thigh')
r_leg_bone = armature.edit_bones.new('r_leg')

# Add bones for the collarbones
l_collarbone_bone = armature.edit_bones.new('l_collarbone')
r_collarbone_bone = armature.edit_bones.new('r_collarbone')

# Add bones for the vertebrae
number_of_vertebrae = 2
vertebrae_bones = []
for i in range(number_of_vertebrae):
    vertebrae_bones.append(armature.edit_bones.new('vertebrae_' + str(i)))


head_length = 0.5
neck_length = 0.2
spine_length = 1.6
pelvis_length = 0.1
pelvis_width =0.25

collarbone_length = 0.35
arm_length = 1.6

thigh_length = 0.7
leg_length = 0.6


# Set the bone lengths and positions
head_bone.head = (0, 0, 0)
head_bone.tail = (0, 0, -head_length)
neck_bone.head = (0, 0, -head_length)
neck_bone.tail = (0, 0, -head_length - neck_length)

# Set the positions of the vertebrae
for i, vertebrae in enumerate(vertebrae_bones):
    vertebrae.head = (0, 0, -head_length - neck_length - i * spine_length/number_of_vertebrae)
    vertebrae.tail = (0, 0, -head_length - neck_length - (i + 1) * spine_length/number_of_vertebrae)

pelvis_bone.head = (0, 0,  -head_length - neck_length - spine_length)
pelvis_bone.tail = (0, 0,  -head_length - neck_length - spine_length - pelvis_length)

# Set the collarbone bone lengths and positions
l_collarbone_bone.head = (0, 0, -head_length - neck_length)
l_collarbone_bone.tail = (-collarbone_length, 0, -head_length - neck_length)
r_collarbone_bone.head = (0, 0, -head_length - neck_length)
r_collarbone_bone.tail = (collarbone_length, 0, -head_length - neck_length)

# Set the arm bone lengths and positions
l_shoulder_bone.head = (-collarbone_length, 0, -head_length - neck_length)
l_shoulder_bone.tail = (-collarbone_length, 0, -head_length - neck_length -arm_length/2)

l_arm_bone.head = (-collarbone_length, 0, -head_length - neck_length -arm_length/2)
l_arm_bone.tail = (-collarbone_length, 0, -head_length - neck_length -arm_length)

r_shoulder_bone.head = (collarbone_length, 0, -head_length - neck_length)
r_shoulder_bone.tail = (collarbone_length, 0, -head_length - neck_length -arm_length/2)
r_arm_bone.head = (collarbone_length, 0, -head_length - neck_length -arm_length/2)
r_arm_bone.tail = (collarbone_length, 0,  -head_length - neck_length -arm_length)

# Set the leg bone lengths and positions
l_thigh_bone.head = (-pelvis_width, 0, -head_length - neck_length - spine_length - pelvis_length)
l_thigh_bone.tail = (-pelvis_width, 0, -head_length - neck_length - spine_length - pelvis_length - thigh_length)
l_leg_bone.head = (-pelvis_width, 0, -head_length - neck_length - spine_length - pelvis_length - thigh_length)
l_leg_bone.tail = (-pelvis_width, 0, -head_length - neck_length - spine_length - pelvis_length - thigh_length - leg_length)
r_thigh_bone.head = (pelvis_width, 0, -head_length - neck_length - spine_length - pelvis_length)
r_thigh_bone.tail = (pelvis_width, 0, -head_length - neck_length - spine_length - pelvis_length - thigh_length)
r_leg_bone.head = (pelvis_width, 0, -head_length - neck_length - spine_length - pelvis_length - thigh_length)
r_leg_bone.tail = (pelvis_width, 0, -head_length - neck_length - spine_length - pelvis_length - thigh_length - leg_length)

# Set the parent-child between the bones
neck_bone.parent = head_bone
pelvis_bone.parent = vertebrae_bones[-1]  # Attach the pelvis to the last vertebrae
l_shoulder_bone.parent = l_collarbone_bone
l_arm_bone.parent = l_shoulder_bone
r_shoulder_bone.parent = r_collarbone_bone
r_arm_bone.parent = r_shoulder_bone
l_thigh_bone.parent = pelvis_bone
l_leg_bone.parent = l_thigh_bone
r_thigh_bone.parent = pelvis_bone
r_leg_bone.parent = r_thigh_bone
l_collarbone_bone.parent = neck_bone
r_collarbone_bone.parent = neck_bone

# Set the parent-child relationships for the vertebrae
for i, vertebrae in enumerate(vertebrae_bones):
    if i == 0:
        vertebrae.parent = neck_bone
    else:
        vertebrae.parent = vertebrae_bones[i-1]
        

bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
obj.select_set(True)

bone_dict = {}

# Loop through the bones in the armature
for bone in armature.edit_bones.values():
    # Add the bone name and head values to the dictionary
    bone_dict[bone.name] = bone.head
for name, head in bone_dict.items():
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=0.3)
    bpy.context.active_object.name = name
    #bpy.context.active_object.location = head
```

this codfe below works but i want to know how i should access a dict properly ( i have tried putting  `bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj obj.select_set(True)` in my loop but it did not work)

```
 bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
obj.select_set(True)
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=0.3, location=(0, 0, 0) )
bpy.context.active_object.name = 'head'

bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
obj.select_set(True)
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=0.3, location=(0, 0, -head_length) )
bpy.context.active_object.name = 'neck'

bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
obj.select_set(True)
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=0.3, location=(0, 0,  -head_length - neck_length - spine_length) )
bpy.context.active_object.name = 'pelvis'

bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
obj.select_set(True)
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=0.3, location=(-collarbone_length, 0, -head_length - neck_length) )
bpy.context.active_object.name = 'l_shoulder'

bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
obj.select_set(True)
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=0.3, location=(-collarbone_length, 0, -head_length - neck_length -arm_length/2) )
bpy.context.active_object.name = 'l_arm'

bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
obj.select_set(True)
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=0.3, location=(collarbone_length, 0, -head_length - neck_length) )
bpy.context.active_object.name = 'r_shoulder'
```

Answer (score 0):

this works

```
for bone in armature.edit_bones.values():
    head = (bone.head.x, bone.head.y, bone.head.z)
    bone_dict[bone.name] = head
    #add_cube_mesh_to_bone(bone.name, 0.3, (bone.head.x, bone.head.y, bone.head.z), (bone.tail.x, bone.tail.y, bone.tail.z))

for name, head in bone_dict.items():
    add_cube_mesh_to_bone(name, 0.3, head, (0, 0, 0))
```

i was passing a reference to the vec3 not the value (i guess) i would like to know why the commented line did not work and it has to construct the full dict first. but this will do.